# Separate keep options for paragraphs

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, paragraph-styles

My project is set in such a way, that the paragraphs should be kept solid. In other words they must not break no matter what.

If the paragraph size exceeds the margins, then the whole paragraph is transferred to another page. Here's how it looks:

[image: paragraphs]

This is set with the following Keep Options
[image: keep options]

Now I need to do the following:

1) **Switch off Keep Options inside the spread**. The paragraph will break to make up for empty space inside the spread.

2) **Turn on Keep Options outside the spread**. The paragraph won't break if it means to transfer part of said paragraph to another spread.

[image]

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Good question! I've never thought about that possibility. Like having an *End Paragraph* option in addition to *Start Paragraph*. Not sure it's possible ... But I wouldn't worry so much about text breaking across spreads. I can see how it's annoying, but it's the way books have been made for hundreds of years so people will figure out to turn the page and look for the rest of the paragraph.

Comment: Edward R. Tufte used this very method in his book "Envisioning Information" (pp.12–15). I'm just looking for a way to achieve this in Indesign

Comment: If I had to do this I think I would just make two styles (with and without keep), only use one of them to begin with, make everything else and as the last thing apply the other style starting from the beginning.

Comment: Interesting puzzle. Imho, if you want to keep your doc flow nicely, you're likely going to need a script.